How to derive canonical link function of exponential distribution in GLM
I want to know the derivation, how to basically calculate it

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Welcome to Cross Validated! Do you mean something like, given the parametric family of the conditional distribution (Poisson, gamma, binomial, Gaussian, etc), what is the canonical link function, almost like a function mapping the likelihood to the canonical link?

GLM is essentially a conditional dispersed version of the exponential family distribution which can be written tersely as $$f(y;θ)=\exp(\frac{θy−b(θ)}{ϕ}+c(y,ϕ))$$, where $ϕ$ is the dispersion parameter, $θ$ is the usual canonical parameter, $b(θ)$ is the log partition function for normalization and $c(y,ϕ)$ is the base measure. On the other hand, for an exponential distribution as a special Gamma distribution with shape $1$ and rate $$ can be expressed as $$f(y;λ)=λ\exp(−λy)=\exp(\log(λ)−λy),y≥0$$ By matching the two terms it's apparent we have $$θ=−λ, b(θ)=−\log(−θ), ϕ=1, c(y,ϕ)=0$$ Furthermore it's well known the relation between the mean $\mu$ of the exponential distribution and its rate $λ$ is $\mu=\frac{1}{λ}$, and the link function $g(μ)$ links the mean $μ$ to the linear predictor $η$ which is nothing but the canonical parameter $θ$ when $g$ is a canonical link function. Therefore we finally arrive at $$g(μ)=η=θ=−λ=-\frac{1}{μ}$$
